# row() return null for specific field

Tags: database, codeigniter, session, model-view-controller, stdclass

Im trying to save specific field from a record into a session, for my user-role. The problem here is i cannot take any other field except **nama**.

controller/verify_login

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('verify_login_model');
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $result = $this->verify_login_model->verify($username, $password);
    if($result == $username) {



        $name = $this->verify_login_model->getinfo($username);
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
        $this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);

        $this->load->view('home_view');






    } else {
        redirect('login');
    }
```

model/verify_login_model

```
function verify($username, $password){
    $this->db->select('username', 'password');
    $this->db->from('tb_user');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()==1) {
        return $username;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function getinfo($username) {
    $this->db->select('nama', 'username');
    $this->db->from('tb_userInfo');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()==1) {

        $result = $query->row();

        return $result->nama;



    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

view

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata['name']?>
```

the var_dump($result) : object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["nama"]=> string(4) "test" }

if i change the return $result->nama; to $result->username; i get error : Undefined property: stdClass::$username even tho im sure 200% there's username field in the table, and tried the query directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your select statement, it must be

```
$this->db->select('nama,username');
```

You are separating each column, and that's not correct, all of the columns go in one string, that's why it tells you its undefined since the only column you are sending is nama and you're sending username as the second parameter for the select.

Here's a link on [active record](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) for **CodeIgniter 2.2.0**